# Where is the bin folder in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, minecraft

I am trying to install Minecraft 1.9 Beta, a website says that I need to drag the .jar file into the bin folder in .Minecraft folder, I don't see bin folder on Ubuntu,what do I do?

Or to make this easier: How do I install Minecraft 1.9 Beta or Snapshot whatever but Minecraft 1.9 on Ubuntu 12.04 right NOW? It's not released officially yet.

Comment: what website? I can take a look and let you know what they are referring to. There are many bin directories.

Comment: http://minecraft.wonderhowto.com/how-to/download-and-install-minecraft-1-9-pre-release-0130100/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Nautilus and press `ctrl + H` to show hidden files. Then start typing `.mine`... to quickly select the folder `.Minecraft` and enter it. There is a folder called `bin`. Enter it, toot, and paste whatever you want to paste there. If these folders don't exist, you probably have to create them.

Since you're new to this page: Please press the tick on the left it this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I didn't know about the tick! I can enter the .Minecraft folder but can't find the bin folder, it exists in Windows 7 but not in Ubuntu 12.04... Maybe I'll just create one :) Thanks